# I am not getting deep link in UPI INTENT API Paytm

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paytm

How to get deep link in UPI INTENT payment method in process API of Paytm gateway.

steps I followed in testing key

1. I got token from initialized api.
2. I passed following body with token to process api
3. I got the error 810 code

[https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/processTransaction?mid=xxxxxx&orderId=".$orderId](https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/processTransaction?mid=xxxxxx&orderId=%22.$orderId)

**Body Params**

```
{"body":{"requestType":"NATIVE","mid":"xxxxx","orderId":"12104870705fe5b90194bd11.05287580","paymentMode":"UPI_INTENT"},"head":{"channelId":"WAP","txnToken":"2f7190a132c44859abef42dbb87123ab1608890631359"}}
```

**Error message**

```
{"head":{"responseTimestamp":"1608890632086","version":"v1"},"body":{"resultInfo":{"resultStatus":"F","resultCode":"0001","resultMsg":"FAILED","retry":false},"txnInfo":{"BANKTXNID":"","CHECKSUMHASH":"ZTYGUUPbhpcpQw0iOmrTI4DvByASuh/Ak3UWb3Sf3uLKX4zAKqttevRIsUOvhA0hO4OKCg6BWRJ9abInxBwFHSbBz6LJ2Bln1FA0fTlJX1M=","CURRENCY":"INR","MID":"xxxxx","ORDERID":"12104870705fe5b90194bd11.05287580","RESPCODE":"810","RESPMSG":"Payment failed due to a technical error. Please try after some time.","STATUS":"TXN_FAILURE","TXNAMOUNT":"1.00"},"callBackUrl":"http://localhost/payment/index.php?orderId=12104870705fe5b90194bd11.05287580&retryAllowed=false&errorMessage=Payment failed due to a technical error. Please try after some time.&errorCode=810"}}
```

Comment: did you get any solution of this issue? I'm also getting the same issue

"RESPCODE": "810",
            "RESPMSG": "Payment failed due to a technical error. Please try after some time.",
            "STATUS": "TXN_FAILURE",